# Combine independent words into a sentence (recognize the first start word)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is  dataframe and the '>>' is the beginning of one sentence. So, any suggestion for that?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'start_time': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1, 1.3],
'end_time': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4],
'word':['>> I','AM','OK','>> HOW', 'ABOUT', 'YOU','>>OK']}
data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['start_time', 'end_time','word'])
df
```

I need to keep >> as the beginning of the sentence, the result is

```
start_time end_time    word

0.1         0.6       >> I AM OK

0.7         1.2       >> HOW ABOUT YOU

1.3         1.4       >>OK
```

I have no idea to get any sentence start with >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you need to split the sentence every time you see the ">>" element:

```py
sentences = []
sentence = ""
for item in word:
    if ">>" == item:
        if sentence:
            sentences.append(sentence)
        sentence = ""
        continue
    sentence += item
```

That should do it, in order to integrate this solution to your dataframe you might need to create a method for this algorithm

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
m=df['word'].str.startswith('>>').cumsum()
```

Finally:

```
out=df.groupby(m).agg({'start_time':'first','end_time':'last','word':' '.join})
```

If needed use `reset_index()`:

```
out=out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**OR**

In 1 Step:

```
out=(df.groupby(df['word'].str.startswith('>>').cumsum())
       .agg({'start_time':'first','end_time':'last','word':' '.join})
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output of `out`:

```
    start_time  end_time    word
0   0.1          0.6        >> I AM OK
1   0.7          1.2        >> HOW ABOUT YOU
2   1.3          1.4        >>OK
```

Comment: @MarkJ. if **this answer** solves your query then you can try considering accepting **this answer** ...Thnx **:)**

Comment: @MarkJ. can you provide explaination that why you accept the another answer since that is incomplete answer?